# PHP Modules not showing on the site but are installed on the server.

Tags: php, centos

I have tried to install APC on my VPS and when I do php -m the APC entry appears in that list. 
OS is centos

However, when I try this

```
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
```

It is not listed in there. I have added

```
extensions=apc.so
```

in the php.ini in the root folder of the web app and in these two files

```
/usr/lib/php.ini
/usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

It is also not showing in the phpinfo page.

Any help is appreciated. I am

Comment: `phpinfo()` will tell you exactly what .ini files it's using. then make sure that the .so files are actually in the appropriate extensions directory. you can't just drop them anywhere on your server and expect php to go looking for them. And of course, restart your server after you make any .ini changes.

Comment: Well that helped a lot and it is greatly appreciated. The extensions directory php was looking in was /usr/lib/... while the module was in /user/local/lib  same path except that the module was installed in a slightly different folder.

Comment: @MarcB you want to add that as the answer so we can close this question? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`phpinfo()` will tell you exactly what .ini files it's using. Then make sure that the .so files are actually in the appropriate extensions directory. You can't just drop them anywhere on your server and expect php to go looking for them. And of course, restart your server after you make any .ini changes